# Populate datagridview with list of strings

Tags: vb.net, list, datagridview

I need to get the data of each of the listof strings

```
    Dim itemsRegiao As New List(Of String)
    Dim itemsProduto As New List(Of String)
    Dim itemsTipoAtividade As New List(Of String)
    Dim itemsAcabamento As New List(Of String)
    Dim itemsCores As New List(Of String)
    Dim itemsGramagem As New List(Of String)
    Dim itemsTipoEmbalagem As New List(Of String)
    Dim itemsFormatos As New List(Of String)
    Dim itemsContagem As New List(Of String)
    Dim itemsTransporte As New List(Of String)
```

to my DataGridView1 where each column has the information of each listofstring.
So i will get 10 columns with the information that is on the list. Dont forget that if i have two String in one of the lists i have to do the combination with the others on the datagridview

Comment: Start with just 3 list. Give us an example of input and output. Right now, it's hard to understand what you want to do. Also, did the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525751/for-loop-to-iterate-through-all-checkedlistboxes-in-a-windows-form/53527475#53527475) helped?

Comment: What you should do is define a type with 10 properties, then use a `For` loop to create instances of that type and populate them with data from the 10 existing lists and add them to a single list, then bind that single list to the grid.  In fact, you should almost certainly do that from the outset and not create these 10 individual lists in the first place.

Comment: dgv.Rows.Add(itemsRegiao(0),itemsProduto(0))...

Comment: What i need to do is this: Imagine i pick in the first checkedlistbox two items and in the rest i pick only one, i need to have 2 rows in the datagridview, i need to get all the combinations possible with the checks i make https://imgur.com/sZaWD9a

Comment: @the_lotus i had to give up with that option because it was too much resource consuming, now i want to do it this way to the datagridview only

Comment: I come up with 451,584 combinations. Who would want to look at all of that?

Comment: IMHO… you are doing this backwards. As @jmcilhinney suggest, make a “Class” for this. Example: Let’s say the new class is named `Specifications` and has properties `Regiao As String`, `Producto As String` … etc.… Then instead of having ten (10) `List`s with a single string in each list, you could have ONE (1) `List` of `Specifications` objects. Once you have a `List<Specifications>` … it should be trivial to export to any `DataCollection` type you need. Managing 10 list’s as you are should be a dead giveaway… that you are doing it wrong!

Comment: @JohnG how can i store the checked values then if i only have 1 list? because i can have more than one item checked and i need to know who it belongs to (if it is a Regiao it has to write in column1, if its produto in column 2...) ?

Comment: You are going to have to explain what you mean by… _”how can i store the checked values then if i only have 1 list?”_ What “checked” values are you talking about? Each List contains string values, not Boolean (checked) values. In addition, your comment _”i can have more than one item checked”_ … “WHERE” is this “Checked” value in the grid? Your question is quickly turning into something that has nothing to do with what you are originally asking. I recommend you clarify your question including “how” this “checked” value is used and where it is in the grid?